# C# get WMI Win32_DiskDrive data by drive letter

Tags: c#, wmi

How can I get the Win32_DiskDrive data by drive letter in C#?
For now I've got this:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT SerialNumber,DeviceID, PNPDeviceID, Caption FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");
ManagementObjectCollection drive = searcher.Get();
```

I'm sure I'd need to add a AND to WHERE statement in the query, but I have no idea how to form it. DeviceID doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing in my diagnostic app. I would look to which ones are strings, boolean, int, etc. And create an iDictionary and program it to each one.

If you look at msdn on all of what your doing it will say what each one is.

I have come across the battery for example I had to create a dictionary list with the code provided.

To pull the values you will have to look at the process code,

Example:

1 = Battery is critical.
2 = Battery is charging.

Or it will have an Ox12, you also have to make sure they are not obsolete. If I am not mistaken DeviceID is obsolete. Your code should go on an example like this:

```
    private void GetBatteryStatus()
    {
        System.Management.ManagementClass wmi = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Battery");
        var allBatteries = wmi.GetInstances();


        foreach (var battery in allBatteries)
        {
            int estimatedChargeRemaining = Convert.ToInt32(battery["EstimatedChargeRemaining"]);
            if (estimatedChargeRemaining == 80)
            {
```

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that I checked the MSDN and I didn't see anything about getting drive letter this way. That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: DeviceIDData type: stringAccess type: Read-onlyQualifiers: CIM_Key 


Address or other identifying information to uniquely name the logical device.